# Why is the query running 3 times, and how can I ensure that the query runs once and the results ensure the data is not undefined at first?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am using [angular-meteor](http://angular-meteor.com) I have removed the `autopublish` package. I can not figure out why the first query is returning `undefined`, and why it is running two more queries for a total of three.

Basically, I want to run a query once, and have its data come back successfully and then populate the page with the results. How can I accomplish this?

In my `routes.js` file that is using `angular-ui-router`:

```
angular.module('projectApp').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
            .state('projectDetail', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/experience/projects',
                templateUrl: 'client/projects/views/project-layout.ng.html',
                controller: 'ProjectDetailsCtrl'
            })
            .state('projectDetail.cards', {
                url: '/:projectId',
                views: {
                    'cards': {
                        templateUrl: 'client/projects/views/partials/project-cards.ng.html',
                        controller: 'ProjectDetailsCtrl'
                    },
                    'toolbar': {
                        templateUrl: 'client/projects/views/partials/project-toolbar.ng.html',
                        controller: 'ProjectDetailsCtrl'
                    }
                }
            });
    }]);
```

**In my `projects.js` publication on the server-side. I want to return a cursor that just contains the project object based on the id passed in from `$stateParams`:**

```
Meteor.publish("project", function(projectId){
    console.log("projectId: ", projectId);
    return Projects.find({ _id: projectId });
});
```

**In my client-side `projectsDetail` controller. I am following the [subscribe](http://angular-meteor.com/api/subscribe) example:**

```
angular
    .module('projectApp')
    .controller("ProjectDetailsCtrl", ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$meteor', 
        function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){ 
           // subscribing to publication here 
            $scope.$meteorSubscribe('project', $stateParams.projectId).then(function(subscriptionHandle){
                $scope.project = $scope.$meteorObject(Projects, $stateParams.projectId);
                console.log("scope project is ready: ", $scope.project);
            });
}]);
```

**The client-side console log shows that the query ran three times. 1st is undefined, 2nd finds the project, and 3rd finds the same project:**

```
scope project is ready:  
SubObject {$$collection: C…s._…n.ns.Collection, $$options: undefined, $$id: undefined, $$internalProps: Array[15], autorunComputation: T…r.Computation} projectDetails.js?b1b67b05e090e366d0853cb2a75b34cc7f75a5d0:10 

scope project is ready:  
SubObject {_id: "zQ8Y938F6HKKqjSdA", image: "/images/large-img-placeholder.jpg", title: "project 1", description: "<p>project 1 description</p>", projectRole: Array[4]…}
    projectDetails.js?b1b67b05e090e366d0853cb2a75b34cc7f75a5d0:10 

scope project is ready:  
SubObject {_id: "zQ8Y938F6HKKqjSdA", image: "/images/large-img-placeholder.jpg", title: "project 1", description: "<p>project 1 description</p>", projectRole: Array[4]…}
```

**The server-side console.log shows the query running 3 times as well:**

```
I20150708-14:36:10.967(-4)? projectId:  null
I20150708-14:36:10.976(-4)? projectId:  zQ8Y938F6HKKqjSdA
I20150708-14:36:10.980(-4)? projectId:  zQ8Y938F6HKKqjSdA
```

Comment: I wonder if it is because the same controller ProjectDetailsCtrl is called in each of the views:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the controller key from the `'projectDetail'` state:

```
.state('projectDetail', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/experience/projects',
                templateUrl: 'client/projects/views/project-layout.ng.html',
                // controller: 'ProjectDetailsCtrl' <- remove
                })
```

and that gets rid of the undefined, and it was returning undefined because there's no `/:projectId` ...

The runs twice because the `controller: 'ProjectDetailsCtrl'` is declared in the `views`